# before_filter not being called Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, before-filter

I have this in my application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    helper_method :mobile_device?
    before_filter :prepare_for_mobile

    private
    def mobile_device?
        request.user_agent=~ /Mobile|webOS/
    end

    def prepare_for_mobile
        request.format = :mobile if mobile_device?
    end
end
```

I am following this railscast video: http://railscasts.com/episodes/199-mobile-devices

The problem is:
When I first load the page it detects mobile browser and gets the request as MOBILE format. But, if I go to any other page on my website, it renders the HTML format instead of MOBILE. If I reload the page, it detects again that the format is MOBILE.

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try using `before_action` instead of `before_filter`.

***edit***: as [paul richter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/877472/paul-richter) mentioned in the comments... `before_filter` will still work. But be aware that Rails is discouraging the use of `before_filter` and suggesting developers to use `before_action` instead.

*source*: [Ruby on Rails 4.2 Release Notes](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html#action-pack-notable-changes)

Comment: Technically `before_filter` is still valid, it hasn't been removed from the core yet (though applications should use `before_action` anyways in anticipation of its removal).

Comment: That is true... for others who need prood... rails 4.2 has discouraged the use of `before_filter` as seen on [Rails 4.2 Release Notes](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html#action-pack-notable-changes)